# Should I add modules to Imports in SharedModule - Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, shared-module

This is my SharedModule

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { IconModule } from "@my-app/components/icon/icon.module";
import { RequiredActionDirective } from "@my-app/directives/required-action.directive";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IconModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RequiredActionDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        IconModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RequiredActionDirective
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Please note that I added to `Imports` only `CommonModule` and `IconModule`. I did it because I'm using those modules in my `RequiredActionDirective`. But `Exports` has more Modules because will be used by other modules that will import `SharedModule`.

Question: am I thinking correctly that I don't need to add Modules to `Imports` unless I want to use them directly in `SharedModule`? Or in future there might be some problems of which I am currently not aware because now everything is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't re-export modules without a reason, and only import modules that the current module depends upon. There is no harm to *import*, but *exporting* creates a *branch* in the dependency tree for providers.

Once a module re-exports a module the parent module importing it can not override that import. So this can be a problem in some edge cases.

For example;

```js
NgModule({
     imports: [HttpClientModule],
     provide: { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ExampleInterceptor, multi: true },
     exports: [HttpClientModule]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Now the AppModule can not provide another interceptor.

```js
NgModule({
     imports: [SharedModule],
     provide: { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptor, multi: true }
     // ^^ interceptor is ignored
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The reason is that the `HttpClientModule` becomes declared in the provider tree at the `SharedModule` level and resolves all `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` from that point *down*.

The requirement is that the `AppModule` should import the `HttpClientModule` first, and then the `SharedModule`.

```js
NgModule({
     imports: [HttpClientModule, SharedModule],
     provide: { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppInterceptor, multi: true }
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now the `HttpClientModule` is declared at the `AppModule` level and resolves all providers *downwards* including the `SharedModule`. The order in the `imports: []` array isn't important.

Comment: I agree but your case takes into account providers which is a different kettle of fish. The assumption of SharedModule is to aggregate most common modules that I want to use almost in each module. And I was asking whether need to import before I'll export them further, but it seems that I don't need to. :)

Answer (score 0):

An NgModule can export a combination of its own declarations, selected imported classes, and imported NgModules.

Don't bother re-exporting pure service modules. Pure service modules don't export declarable classes that another NgModule could use. For example, there's no point in re-exporting HttpClientModule because it doesn't export anything. Its only purpose is to add http service providers to the application as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you are correct. You could even technically get rid of `CommonModule` from imports in `SharedModule`, but there is a high chance that some of the stuff may need it now or later, so I would not recommend it.

Also in terms of `CommonModule`:
Notice that `CommonModule` is automatically added to imports when generating new module using CLI. It means that it is available right away, however it can be safely deleted since we already export it in `SharedModule`. It can be useful when optimizing redundant imports, but it's really up to you.